# Password-protected web pages when accessed by Android

Tags: android, html, password-protection

I have created a password protected static html page with a custom audio player, to be displayed in any browser and OSs. User/password access to the page works fine from any browser. But none of my attempts to make the player work for Android browsers worked. This is the link I have:

```
   <a title="play mp3 in new window" target="_blank" href="01.mp3"><img border="0" src="play.gif"></a>
```

If I remove the password, the player works in Android as well, so this would suggest an issue with playing media files on Android when the directory is password protected. The files are indeed in the same folder as the web page.

Thanks for any help,

Joe

Answer (score 3):

You have to add your autorization to the webview headers:

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("Authorization", "Basic" + Base64.encodeToString(username + ':' + password),Base64.DEFAULT);
```

And then when you load your url add the headers as the second parameter.

```
webview.loadUrl("www.mysite.com",headers);
```

You can also use [setHttpAuthUsernamePassword](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setHttpAuthUsernamePassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: Hi Pedro. Thanks for the quickest reply. I must be missing a vital piece of knowledge here, or maybe my question was misleading. I am working on a a normal html page. Where/how do I use the webview authorisation headers in a static html page?

Comment: How are you displaying the page on Android?

Comment: Simply using the normal browser and going to the web page url.

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I am trying to achieve that a web page which is password protected and contains mp3 file links, can play the mp3 files when the page is displayed in an Android browser. When the password protection is taken out, the mp3 file links can play the file correctly. When the password protection is on, the mp3 file links can still be clicked on but the file is not played, no sound comes out of the Android phone.